# Buffered pipe in bash

Tags: bash, bukkit

I'm running a Bukkit (Minecraft) server on a Linux machine and I want to have the server gracefully shut down using the server's `stop` command and the computer suspend at a certain time using `pm-suspend` from the command line. Here's what I've got:

```
me@comp~/dir$ perl -e 'sleep [time]; print "stop\\n";' | ./server && sudo pm-suspend
```

(I've edited by `/etc/sudoers` so I don't have to enter my password when I suspend.)

The thing is, while the `perl -e` is sleeping, the server is expecting a constant stream of bytes, (That's my guess. I could be misunderstanding something.) so it prints out all of the nothings it receives, taking up precious resources:

```
me@comp~/dir$ ...
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>...
```

Is there any such thing as a buffered pipe? If not, are there any ways to send delayed input to a script?

Comment: This behavior could be because bukkit server is expecting standard input to be attached to a terminal. Your redirection breaks this assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [Bukkit's wiki](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Setting_up_a_server#Linux), which recommends an [init script](https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init/blob/master/readme.markdown) for permanently running servers.

This init script uses rather unconventional approach to communicate with running server. The server is started in [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) session, then all commands are send to the server console via screen, e.g.

`screen -p 0 -S $SCREEN -X eval 'stuff \"stop\"\015'`

See https://github.com/Ahtenus/minecraft-init/blob/master/minecraft

This approach suggest that bukkit may be expecting standard input to be attached to a terminal, thus requiring screen wrapper (which is itself terminal emulator) for unattended runs.